# Earth Engine: logical && on two boolean variables derived from server-based objects

Tags: google-earth-engine

I got two variables derived from server-based objects:

```
var Ind16Bin = (ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(G16ind, G16indOLD));  
var Ind17Bin = (ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(G17ind, G17indOLD));
```

both variables evaluate correctly.
When variables combined using && operator:

```
var IndBothBin = (Ind17Bin && Ind16Bin);
```

it acts as if first variable in brackets is always 'true'.
I can change order of variables in brackets. The first one always evaluated as 'true'.
How to write it correctly?

Code is here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/2f94fcc9047f51360b6f6f92712cdf62
It is quite long. The line of interest is on line 70